# Crystal Report : How to use Hyperlink for desktop Base program

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, hyperlink, reporting

I am using Crystal Report with C#.
For Desktop.

I want to hyperlink to another report with some parameter.

eg. I show Invoice's Summary (invoice.rpt) like its number (named InvNo), date, items and TotalAmount.
If i click InvNo "0001", then it will passing the InvNo to Item's Summary (item.rpt)

Is it possible?

IF possible, i think it will need some code in crystal report formula, please give me the formula example too.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought the answer was 'not possible', but after some experimentation I got farther than I expected.

I created two reports based on the Xtreme.mdb file, named customers.rpt and order.rpt.

The customer.rpt has two columns: Customer Name and Order ID.  The order.rpt has three columns: Order ID, Order Date, and Order Amount.

The goal: if I click on the Order ID field in the customers report it opens the order report and generates it for that Order ID.

I added the following to the condition formula associated with the Order ID's Hyperlink:

```
"file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/order.rpt " + ToText({Orders.Order ID},"#")
```

When I click on the link, I get the following dialog:

[image]

Unfortunately, Crystal Reports' EXE doesn't support command-line arguments, so the action fails:

[image]

To get this to work, you would need to create an application that can process the command-line arguments for Crystal Reports.  It would have the following characteristics:

- packaged as an EXE
- 'wrap' the Crystal Report Viewer control (you probably don't need any 'design' functionality)
- handle database authentication
- most importantly, it needs to support command-line arguments.  in this regard, you could probably model your argument list on BusinessObjecs's [URL Reporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html).